# Vue error : The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I started working with Nuxt a few days ago and I had a case where I need to nest nuxt link's like this

```
  <nuxt-link to="/home">
    Test 1
    <nuxt-link to="/home"> 
      Test 2
    </nuxt-link>
  </nuxt-link>
```

But the console throws the following error.

> [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching
>   server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML
>   markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside
>
> , or
>   missing . Bailing hydration and performing full client-side
>   render.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Well, you can't have a link inside a link. If you click on "test 2", in your case, what should the browser do? Go twice to /home?

Comment: Well we have an image with a button on it. On desktop we  want the button to be a link and on mobile we want the image to be a link. All the images with buttons on it  are being drawn in a for loop.